# Xamarin Page.Title access but not as a string

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, master-pages, flyout

I want to access the `page.title` or `this.title` but not as a string and instead as an element or anything other than a string in which I can then convert to a visual element.

The reason I want to do this is that I need to force move my accessibility to the top of the page but can't when `this.title`  can only be referenced as a string. I know that `page.title` is accessible in iOS, and on Android it is accessible but instead highlights the whole page. (talk back and voice-over)

Is this possible? I have tried to do something similar by using `Navigationpage.TitleView`  and then accessing the label inside of the title view which is label/view/visual element, but you can not place a titleview inside of master detail or flyout page. My page is a split view so contains its own title separate from the two pages nestled inside.

Comment: Remove the toolbar using `Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"` for shell or `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false"` for regular pages and create your own toolbar with XF controls

Comment: `Navigationpage.TitleView` is the correct way , it can be used inside the page which is wrapped inside navigation ,  if you want to custom `TitleView` inside flyout page , you can try to wrap `flyout page` inside navigation ,but it is not recommended.